# macro implementations cannot have implicit parameters other than WeakTypeTag evidences

Tags: scala

I am using: Scala 2.12.4. With the following code:

```
implicit class RichInFix[T](body: => T) {
  def toEither[E <: MyType]: Either[E, T] = macro Macros.toEitherImpl
}

object Macros {
  def toEitherImpl[E : WeakTypeTag, T : WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[Either[E, T]] = ???
}
```

I get the following compile error: `macro implementations cannot have implicit parameters other than WeakTypeTag evidences`.

I can't see whether I am going wrong, both E & T are WeakTypeTags - any ideas?

Comment: Try using `c.WeakTypeTag`, instead of plain type

Comment: I thought the same as @L.Lampart - was about to post it as an answer, but tried it and came up with the same error.